# How to use xclip to concatenate clipboard contents to file?

Tags: ubuntu

How to use xclip to concatenate clipboard contents to file?

I am browsing the Internet and making research. I want to be able to copy paste a url and have xclip concatenate it to a file.

Example.

www.urlhere.com

I want to copy the url with ctrl+c and then have xclip concatenate the url to the file urls.txt

I have downloaded xclip.

I have tested these inputs but they are incorrect:

xclip -selection clipboard urls.txt

xclip -i urls.txt

Halp

Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command "echo $(xclip -o -clipboard) >> destination.txt" will append the contents of the clipboard to the file, followed by a newline. You could set up a hotkey to execute that command.

Comment: Ah, yes, it works. And yes again, my idea exactly. Pretty sweet huh : )?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you didn't suggest `xclip -o -clipboard >> destination.txt`?